# MongoDB distinct returns empty

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I can't get collection.distinct to work for me on db.version '4.4.3'. I'm following the example at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/distinct/

```
{ "_id": 1, "dept": "A", "item": { "sku": "111", "color": "red" }, "sizes": [ "S", "M" ] }
{ "_id": 2, "dept": "A", "item": { "sku": "111", "color": "blue" }, "sizes": [ "M", "L" ] }
{ "_id": 3, "dept": "B", "item": { "sku": "222", "color": "blue" }, "sizes": "S" }
{ "_id": 4, "dept": "A", "item": { "sku": "333", "color": "black" }, "sizes": [ "S" ] }
```

Then run

```
db.runCommand ( { distinct: "inventory", key: "dept" } )
```

I get

```
{ values: [], ok: 1 }
```

This doesn't work either:

```
db.inventory.distinct( "dept" )

[]
```

I can't get it to work on a local server or a remote server. What gives?

Comment: Are you switching to your db before running commands? ie: `use my-database-name` Does find() work?

Comment: That worked! Thank you!